# I want to pass a variable as a parameter to .hasClass():

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a variable as a parameter to `.hasClass()`:

```
data = is specialclass
if($(".concon").hasClass(data))
{
    //do some thing
}
```

However this does not seem to work. How can I use a class-name stored in a variable with this method?

Comment: Sorry, but your English is so hard to understand that we can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: The name of your variable is `date` but you try and reference it as `data` -- could that be the problem?

Comment: iam  sorry for English   in my source code  i wright data and data

Comment: Class names must begin with a letter (i.e. it can't be `1`). Try changing that and see if that helps.

Comment: data back with ajax put i right hear for exampled  . this not Trouble i tray var data ="test" not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Include jquery here

var the_class_name = "specialclass"; 

if($(".concon").hasClass(the_class_name))
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: I believe "data" is a keyword that is reserved for ajax requests.

Answer (score 4):

When you use

`var data = 1 ;`

you are passing a number, but you want to pass a string

`var data = "1" ;`